# Exception in ClosedXML GetString with Excel formula

Tags: c#, closedxml

I am opening an Excel spreadsheet and processing it.  When I get to a cell that contains a formula (LOOKUP in this case), there is an exception:

`Cannot convert Submission!G6's value to System.String`

This is happening in this line of code:

```
        var values = row.Cells(1, lastColumnNumber)
            .Select(x => x.GetString())
            .ToArray();
```

There is also a Github issue for this https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/issues/1217

How do I get the calculated "value" from the cell?

Answer (score 4):

As noted, this is actually an issue with ClosedXML.
But!  There is a workaround.  You can call `CachedValue` instead of `Value`.
Here is the code, fixed:

```
        var values = row.Cells(1, lastColumnNumber)
            .Select(x => x.CachedValue?.ToString())
            .ToArray();
```

From the [documentation, CachedValue](https://closedxml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cell.html?highlight=cachedvalue) holds the result of the calculation/formula.

Comment: What if the property `NeedsRecalculation` is set to `true`? How you can force the recalculation? I have noticed that `GetFormattedString()` seems always to return a text even if `Value` or `GetString()` are throwing exception

Comment: Hi @KillKRT, I'm sorry - I don't know.

Comment: I've found that you can do at worksheet level using `RecalculateAllFormulas`